# rand() повторяет одно и то же число

Tags: php, случайные-числа

у меня есть код

```
$arr = [
[
'str_a' => 'А',
'str_a1' => 'А1',
'str_a2' => 'А2',
'str_a3' => 'А3',
'str_a4' => 'А4',
'str_a5' => 'А5',
],
[
'str_a' => 'А',
'str_a1' => 'А1',
'str_a2' => 'А2',
'str_a3' => 'А3',
'str_a4' => 'А4',
'str_a5' => 'А5',
]
];


$random = rand(1,5);

foreach($arr as $val) {
    shuffle($arr);
    echo $val['str_a'];
    echo $val['str_a'.$random];
    echo $val['str_a'.$random];
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы рандом не выдал тот же число?

Пробовал так но он повторяет одиноковые число.

```
    echo $val['str_a'];
    echo $val['str_a'.rand(1,5)];
    echo $val['str_a'.rand(1,5)];
```

Если в первом строке получил число 2, я хочу не повторять это число во втором строке.

Comment: Показанный вами «Пробовал так» выдаёт вполне случайные числа. А случайность подразумевает в том числе то, что случайно может быть повтор. А если вы не хотите повторов, то значит вам нужно как-то запоминать значения, которые вы желаете не повторять

Comment: А как запоминать? В $_SESSION? я нуб

Comment: строчка ``$random = rand(1,5);`` выполняется только один раз. Поэтому число в ``$random`` и не меняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `array_pop` — извлекает последний элемент массива

```
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $min = 1; $arNum = [];
    $max = count($val)-1; // 5
    while ($min <= $max) $arNum[] = $min++;
    shuffle($arNum); // [1,5,3,4,2]
    echo $val['str_a'];
    echo $val['str_a'.array_pop($arNum)]; // 2
    echo $val['str_a'.array_pop($arNum)]; // 4
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!